# Sewer Line Installation

Tags: sewer, septic

I am running a septic line from my mancave to the main 4" sewer line coming out of my house.

I want to splice into this line coming out of the house.

The total run is 60'; is this ok to do?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram of what you're planning would be helpful. Including altitudes would also help, so that we could think about slopes (which is important for sewage flow).

Comment: the grade is level from mancave to septic line, 60'.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you can get the required slope on the line.

Waste lines larger than 2" are required to drop 1/4" for every 12" of run. So, this line must drop 1 1/2" for every 10 feet or 9" for 60 feet overall.

Can you get that much vertical drop in you line?

If not, you are asking for a clogged line and backed up toilet and nobody likes that.

Good luck!